# Regular Expression Issue - Validate Email Address - Android

Tags: android, regex

Why does it require me to hit a space and a backspace in order for the Error to disappear in the EditText widget after I type the email address in the EditText widget?  Here is the source code I'm using:

```
if (!Pattern.matches("^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+(?:[A-Z {2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|in|aero|jobs|museum)$", s)) {
                    et.setError("please enter a valid email address");
}
```

Why is it doing this?  What am I doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `the Error` - what error?

Comment: The error that shows up next to the EditText when an invalid email address is not entered.  That is what the et.setError() method does is it displays the error.

Comment: There looks to be an unrelated typo in your regex `[  <-- Unbalanced  '['  A-Z {2}`

Comment: That should fix that problem.

Comment: That actually didn't fix the issue with having to hit a space and backspace after entering the email address in order to get rid of the error.

Comment: I didn't say that fixed your primary problem, I said it fixes the problem where your regex won't even compile. How did it compile?

Comment: I got it to compile and actually made some other changes to my code and it actually worked.  If you want add the answer below and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try by this:

```
boolean isValid = android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher("any@e-mail.com").matches();
```

Actually any regexp you could provide for checking e-mail addresses will be not enough because this has a **huge** set of possibilities (now there are even domains with more than 3 letters as TLD...).

Android provides this kind of methods, so it's a good idea using them and save up the headache.